# infinitely reuse jquery ui dialogue and javascript for 'n' number of parent items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to reuse a jQuery UI dialog infinite number of times. In another words, I have a dialog that creates an Item, however, there is an option on this dialog to set the item as a subitem of another or create a new parent. I need to be able to reuse this dialog without creating hundreds (hopefully the end use will not need that many) of unique instances.

Comment: Please, ask your question

Comment: OK... How is this done?

Comment: Where do we start? What does your code look like? We're completely in the mist here. You give a very vague idea of what you want and you expect us to develop for you a miracle solution. That's not how it works. You have to come here with a precise question and share your code, so we can help you _debug_ it. We're not supposed to develop stuff for you.

Comment: Not my intention to have anyone do the codeing for me. 1. Need to know if it is at all possible. And 2. If possible, are there any examples out there.

Comment: At the current moment, the html and JS is about 40% complete so I do not have anything to post yet.